# Google maps V3 Geocoding multiple markers (address from xml) and problem with infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I tried to search so much but could not find any solutions that fits my map!

I want to build a website that people can upload photos of the weather and displaying it on a google map. Everything was OK until I wanted to use Geocoding ! In fact, the markers are in the good position but the infowindow is always the same (last marker infowindow). I'm getting the address ("name") from a php file that parse XML from an SQL database.
I know few people had the same problem, but even with their solutions, it does not fit.

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>皆の天気ｂｙロマンスカイ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styletenki.css" />
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleie.css" />
        <![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;

function load() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("googleapitest.php", function (data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var date = markers[i].getAttribute("date");
      //var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      //   parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lgn")));
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var temperature = markers[i].getAttribute("temperature");
      var cloud = markers[i].getAttribute("cloud");
      var comment = markers[i].getAttribute("comment");

      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + temperature + "</b> <br/>" + cloud + "</b> <br/>" + comment;

      //var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

      /* Appel au service de geocodage avec l'adresse en parametre */
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': name
      }, function (results, status) {
        /* Si l'adresse a pu etre geolocalisee */
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

          /* Affichage du marker */
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });

          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
  </script>

  </head>

  <body onLoad="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `html` variable used in `bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);` is changed during the for loop. When callback of `geocoder.geocode` is called, that's the last value of `html` that is used for all your markers. To work around this problem, you have to capture value of `html` with a closure. Something like :

```js
(function(capturedHtml){
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': name
  }, function (results, status) {
    /* Si l'adresse a pu etre geolocalisee */
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      /* Affichage du marker */
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, capturedHtml);
    }
  });
})(html);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works ! I should learn more Javascript to solve the problem myself next time ! ^^ Thank you again.